# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' in VSCode

Tags: c, windows

I only started my c learning process in university and doesn't even familiar with the basics but after running this code in VScode:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char personName[50];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s",personName);

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
C:\Users\1\Desktop\HTMLCC\C> cd "c:\Users\1\Desktop\HTMLCC\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc main.c -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Reinstalling MinGw and all the C/C++ extensions in VSCode didn't help.

Comment: This:  "undefined reference to `WinMain@16" -- makes me think maybe you defined your projects as "win32" or "windows" when you should have picked "console."  Please check your project properties.

Comment: Did you save your file before compiling? That's a common VSCode issue.

Comment: Omg, thank you very much for that saving reminder, it works finally )